# How to "translate" this scanner input into a JOptionPane showOptionDialog

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I am trying to make my code more user friendly. I have this part of code and would like to know how can I convert it to joptionpane.
I found this  `int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, "Continue printing?");`
but seems a bit weird to use another jframe for it.

```
System.out.println("Make more selections? Type Yes or No");

Scanner scanre = new Scanner( System.in );
String selecend;
selecend = scanre.next();
if(selecend.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {
    System.out.println("Enter next selection: ");
    query();
};
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)  I mean *besides* asking us.  BTW - *"but seems a bit weird to use another jframe for it."*  So use whatever frame you *have*, but note that argument can also be a component, or `null`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> more user friendly

What about the next?

```
private Something showMessage() {

    // null for 'console' mode or this if the enclosing type is a frame
    Component parentComponent = null; 
    Object message = "Make more selections?";
    String title = "Message";
    int optionType = JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION; // 2 buttons
    int messageType = JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE; // icon from style
    Icon icon = null;

    // String in the buttons!
    Object[] options = { "Yup!", "Nope!" };

    // option saves the index 'clicked'
    int option = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(
            parentComponent, message, title, 
            optionType, messageType, icon,
            options, options[0]);

    switch (option) {
    case 0:
        // button with "Yup!"
        break;
    case 1:
        // button with "Nope!"
        break;
    default:
        // you close the dialog or press 'escape'
        break;
    }

    return Something;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you may want to use a JFrame since there you can change all your System out print messages to use something like a label status (a JLabel that would change the text based on the message)
Still you don't need to use a frame to use showConfirmDialog.

```
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"choose one", "choose one", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
```

You can check for examples and documentation of [JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html)

The frame in your example is the parent for this dialog message:

```
parentComponent - 
determines the Frame in which the dialog is displayed; 
if null, or if the parentComponent has no Frame, a default Frame is used
```

I think this parent is used to prevent the focus on the parent frame if the dialog is alive. Something similar to windows alerts when you have to accept or close a dialog before continue using a program, it locks the gui.

Answer (score 1):

tried this and works:

```
int dialogresult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (null, "Continue Selecting?");

                       if(dialogresult == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                           query();
                       }else if(dialogresult == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {

                       }
```